# Wordpress: How to add target="_blank" to links within dynamic_sidebar?

Tags: wordpress

I'm using BeTheme theme in WordPress and I'm tring to customize the footer. I defined its links in the administration panel of Wordpress (Appearance > Menus and here I created a new menu, I selected it and filled it with Customized links).

I know that the BeTheme file `footer.php`, located in the root of the theme directory, contains the call `dynamic_sidebar( 'footer-area-'. $i );` to show the footer's columns, which contain the links.

Do you know how to customize the HTML code of these links, in order to add `target="_blank"`?

Comment: You don't need to modify HTML code. Just enable the "Link Target" from "Show advanced menu properties" in Screen Options. You can do that by opening the screen options (found under the top bar) while being on Appearance > Menus page.

Comment: You should post an answer, even if it doesn't match the question stricto sensus :).